# How to read String as Object?

Tags: java, oop

I call timeline() in class testeAD1, I have posts made by user in a list in class Amigo, I used hasNext, so for each item in list I want to get item.posts (which .posts is in Class Amigo), but I get a "cannot convert String to Amigo". I am new to OOP in Java, this is a college project, please help.

I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator to Iterator
at Rede.timeline(testeAD1.java:34)
at testeAD1.main(testeAD1.java:117)

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

class Post{
    
    
    String post;
    public int qntCurtidas;
    
        
    
    Post(String pPost){
        post = pPost;
    }
    
    
}

class Rede {
    
    List<String> usuarios = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    String I;

    
    public void adicionarAmigo(Amigo pNome) {
        usuarios.add(pNome.nome);
    }
    
    
    public void timeline() {
        Iterator<String> it = usuarios.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next().posts);
        
        
        }
    }
}


class Amigo {
    
    
    String nome;
    
    List<String> posts = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> curtidas = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    
    Amigo(String pNome){
        nome = pNome;       
    }
    
    
    public void postar(Post pPost) {
        posts.add(pPost.post);
    }
    
    public void curtir(Post pPost) {
        curtidas.add(pPost.post);
        pPost.qntCurtidas += 1;
        
    }
    
    

    
}


public class testeAD1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        Amigo fulano = new Amigo("Fulano");
        Amigo ciclano = new Amigo("Ciclano");
        Amigo beltrano = new Amigo("Beltrano");
        Rede paraiso = new Rede();
        paraiso.adicionarAmigo(fulano);
        paraiso.adicionarAmigo(ciclano);
        paraiso.adicionarAmigo(beltrano);
        Post bomdia = new Post("Bom dia!");
        Post boatarde = new Post("Bom tarde!");
        Post boanoite = new Post("Bom noite!");
        fulano.postar(bomdia);
        fulano.postar(boatarde);
        ciclano.postar(boanoite);
        beltrano.curtir(bomdia);
        beltrano.curtir(boatarde);
        beltrano.curtir(boanoite);
        fulano.curtir(boanoite);
        
        
        /* DEBUG */
        System.out.println(fulano.nome);
        System.out.println(ciclano.nome);
        System.out.println(beltrano.nome);
        System.out.println("USERS IN NETWORK(REDE)");
        System.out.println(paraiso.usuarios);
        System.out.println("POSTS MADE BY USER");
        System.out.println(fulano.posts);
        System.out.println(ciclano.posts);
        System.out.println(beltrano.posts);
        System.out.println("POSTS LIKED BY USER");
        System.out.println(beltrano.curtidas);
        System.out.println(fulano.curtidas);
        System.out.println(ciclano.curtidas);
        System.out.println("NUMBER OF LIKES FOR EACH POST");
        System.out.println(bomdia.qntCurtidas);
        System.out.println(boatarde.qntCurtidas);
        System.out.println(boanoite.qntCurtidas);
        System.out.println("Timeline:");
        paraiso.timeline();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I get a "cannot convert String to Amigo". "*  - Where?  What line?

Comment: Look at your main method and see what it does, do the same thing.

Comment: I don't get it, what do u mean my main method

Comment: In Rede.timeline() you have a line ``Amigo HA = I;`` where I is a String. You might have meant ``Amigo HA = new Amigo(I);``.

Comment: Then I would create another object in Amigo, what I want to do is, from the list usuarios = [Fulano, Ciclano, Beltrano], I want to get .posts from each item in list, Fulano.posts, Ciclano.posts and Beltrano.posts, How do I do that?

Comment: If you are capable of creating screenshots you should also be capable of copying an error message as plain text. Don’t require your readers to follow a link to a picture. And provided the *shortest* code for reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your classes as below. Otherwise, Post and Amigo classes are unnecessary. You need to store Post in List, instead of store String. Same for Amigo.

Your classes need more modification to achieve actual oop behavior.

```
class Post {

    String post;
    public int qntCurtidas;

    Post(String pPost) {
        post = pPost;
    }

}

class Rede {

    List<Amigo> usuarios = new ArrayList<Amigo>();
    
    String I;

    public void adicionarAmigo(Amigo pNome) {
        usuarios.add(pNome);
    }

    public void timeline() {
        Iterator<Amigo> it = usuarios.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Amigo I = it.next();
            Amigo HA = I;
            System.out.println(HA.posts);
        }
    }
    
}

class Amigo {

    String nome;

    List<Post> posts = null; 
    List<Post> curtidas = null; 

    Amigo(String pNome) {
        nome = pNome;
        posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
        curtidas = new ArrayList<Post>();
    }

    public void postar(Post pPost) {
        posts.add(pPost);
    }

    public void curtir(Post pPost) {
        curtidas.add(pPost);
        pPost.qntCurtidas += 1;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to asset Amigo to String? Why?
They are different type of objects.

```
String I = it.next();
    Amigo HA = I;
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the string from the list and read as object Amigo so I can get Amigo.posts from the list, in this case the list is [Fulano, Ciclano, Beltrano], I am trying to get Fulano.posts, Ciclano.posts and Beltrano.posts. How can I do that?